# Help with this simple derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

I'm trying to solve this question from the classical Do Carmo's Differential geometry book. Surprisingly for me, I'm stuck on a very simple question on page 25:

[image]

### MY SOLUTION:

Suppose we have already proved $dt/ds=1/|\alpha'|$ Since he wants the second derivative $d^2t/ds^2$ of $dt/ds$, we have:

$$\frac{d^2t}{ds^2}=(|\alpha'(t)|^{-1})'=-|\alpha'(t)|^{-2}|\alpha'(t)|'=-\frac{|\alpha'(t)|'}{|\alpha'(t)|^2}$$

Since $|\alpha'(t)|'=\frac{\alpha'(t)\alpha''(t)}{|\alpha'(t)|}$, we have

$$d^2t/ds^2=-\frac{\alpha'(t)\alpha''(t)}{|\alpha'(t)|^3}$$

So where is my mistake?

Comment: Be careful with your primes.  I think you took the derivative with respect to $s$ on one side and with respect to $t$ on the other.  The difference would be a factor of $\frac{dt}{ds} = \frac{1}{|\mathbf{\alpha}'(t)|}$

Comment: Throughout the study of curves in differential geometry, you *must* pay attention to the chain rule! If it helps, I make this more explicit—with lots of examples—than doCarmo in my [differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Of course, thank you!

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for the book recommendation, I've already known your book, very good one. I've forgotten the chain rule, how dumb I am! Now I solved this question, thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you differentiate $|\alpha^{\prime}|^{-1}$ with respect to $s$, and you write $|\alpha^{\prime}|^{\prime}$ but the primes mean differentiation with respect to $t$. So your calculation is the derivative of $|\alpha^{\prime}|^{-1}$ with respect to $t$, and not $s$. Correcting this with another chain rule gives the correct answer.